# Check install drive format

Tags: visual-studio-2017, setup-project, visual-studio-setup-proje

I want to make sure that the drive I'm currently installing to is a certain format (e.g. NTFS, exFAT, FAT32, etc.). I was thinking there might be a condition I can check or something before installing.

Since I can't check the install format with conditions, is there some other approach I can take in order to get this?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a standard property that denotes this, in the list here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/property-reference

The difficulty is that there might be a variety of drive formats on the system and the check can't be made until the user browses for an install location which might be one type or another. Visual Studio setups don't support running code when that install location has been chosen.

Is there an underlying problem (perhaps with the app) that this is attempting to solve?

Comment: I was hoping I could put the condition check after the user clicks "next" on the setup when they select their location. My software is supposed to be installed on a thumbdrive, and in order to maintain invisibility (its purpose), it needs to be installed on some drive with USN Journal disabled. I'd settle for just "exFAT" or something at this point :/

Comment: Sounds kinda nefarious, but there might be better ways of installing. I'm pretty sure stuxnet didn't use VS setup projects :-)  But even then, assuming you have administrative rights, you can always delete the USN journal. The fsutil utility can do that, for example: `fsutil usn deletejournal /d g:` is something you can script.